# Direction & order of strokes when writing letters

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, safrus

When writing Torah scrolls, mezuzahs, or tefillin scrolls, is there any significance to the direction of the strokes of the pen for each letter?   Or the order of the strokes for each letter?
IE:  (If it matters, I am a lefty)  For an aleph, I start with the upper left and do the long stroke down to the right, then the left small stroke down, and the right small stroke up.

Comment: Radak Isaiah 10:19

Answer (score 1):

When I was learning to write I asked my teacher the same question and was told that there is no significance to the order or direction other then this is what makes the nicest letters. I suspect that a chasidish or sefardik/kabalistic sofer may have learned differently.